# Difference between numpy's np.transpose(matrix) and np.matrix.transpose() on a 2D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

Is there a functional difference between numpy's np.transpose(matrix) and np.matrix.transpose() on a 2D matrix, given no axes specified in either?

Also, could someone try to intuitively explain how the axes specification works?

Thanks!

Comment: Stay away from np.matrix for now.  It will only confuse you

Answer (score 0):

```
In [16]: np.matrix.transpose
Out[16]: <method 'transpose' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects>
```

This is the same as `np.ndarray.transpose`.  In other words it's the `transpose` method that `np.matrix` subclass inherits from the parent `np.ndarray` (what we typically call `numpy` array).

`np.transpose` is the function equivalent, which ends up calling the transpose method.  It's different in that it can convert its input to an array first, e.g. if the input is a list.  Lists, of course, don't have a transpose method.

As for what it does - with a 2d array it does the usual mathematically defined transpose.  What can confuse users from other languages, is that it generalized the concept to 1d, 3d, and higher.  While you are at it make sure you understand the difference between a 1d and a 2d array.  If you aren't clear about that, transpose will remain a puzzle.

Transpose and its axes parameter has been explained in other SO question.  I'd suggest reading the docs along side an interactive session in which you can play with arrays with various dimensions.

```
In [23]: x = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
In [24]: x.transpose().shape
Out[24]: (4, 3, 2)
In [25]: x.transpose(0,2,1).shape
Out[25]: (2, 4, 3)
```

Don't try to carry over MATLAB intuitions.